# Hide login form from the logged user in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I need help. I have a form login. After login, the app sends me to my account page and it's fine. But if I go back to the page where the login form is, the login form reappears. I would like for the login form to disappear after login. Could you help me please?

Here is the code and the link for the login page:

```html
<div id="login-code-container"><form id="loginform" action="/wp-login.php" method="post" name="loginform">
<p class="login-username"><label for="user_login">Nombre de usuario o dirección de correo</label>
<input id="user_login" class="input" name="log" size="20" type="text" value="" /></p>
<p class="login-password"><label for="user_pass">Contraseña</label>
<input id="user_pass" class="input" name="pwd" size="20" type="password" value="" /></p>
<p class="login-submit"><input id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary" name="wp-submit" type="submit" value="Acceder" />
<input name="redirect_to" type="hidden" value="/" /></p>

</form><a href="/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=%2F">Desconectar</a>

</div>
```

Page: https://testcucu4.mystagingwebsite.com/checkout-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new shortcode for this. You have to paste the code at the current theme > functions.php. You can create a shortcode like this :

```
add_shortcode( 'user_control', 'user_control_func' );
    function user_control_func() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       wp_redirect('/')
      }    
    }
```

And you will add shortcode the login form page like this:

```
 [user_control]
```